# sudo: editor: command not found

Tags: command-line, sudo

I am trying to install gitlab on my server but when I run this command:

```
sudo -u git -H editor config/gitlab.yml
```

then I get:

```
sudo: editor: command not found
```

cn you guys tell me what is the wrong with this command, I am following this instruction for installing GitLab:

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/install/centos/README.md

I am not much familiar to Linux and SSH commands, so be gentle with me. Thanks

Comment: Newcomers often use the `nano` editor.  Does `sudo -u git -H nano config/gitlab.yml` work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `editor` command doesn't exist by default. In the tutorial you are using they are making `editor` as an alias for `vim` earlier.

You can just use `vim` (advanced) or `nano` (easy) instead of `editor`.

Comment: Doesn't it? `which editor` shows me `/usr/bin/editor`... That should exist for all users.

Comment: @Oli I agree. /usr/bin/editor links to /etc/alternatives/editor, which links to /bin/nano on both of my systems.

Comment: @Oli Yeah you're right, my bad. But it is a symlink which he may have accidentally [removed](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/install/centos/README.md#configure-the-default-editor) (if he just executed all commands in the tutorial).